# Clickable link in pdf to open up different file types in iText 5

Tags: java, itext

I tried to make a clickable link in iText 5 for pdf managing using java, So that once the link in the pdf is clicked, it will open up the expected file-type which can be an image, pdf, .csv etc.

> Note that the clickable link is not a url/any remote file, it expects to open up the file itself like data.pdf/data.csv/data.jpeg.

I have also added below code for the same:

```
String testData = "data:@file/png;base64,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";
        Phrase phrase = new Phrase("");
        Font anchorFont = new Font(Font.FontFamily.UNDEFINED, 11);
        anchorFont.setColor(BaseColor.BLUE);
        anchorFont.setStyle(Font.FontStyle.UNDERLINE.getValue());

        Anchor anchor1 = new Anchor("Click to Open", anchorFont);
        anchor1.setReference(testData);
        
        phrase.add(anchor1);
        subPara.add(phrase);
```

testData values can be of different file type values like "data:application/pdf;base64,JVBERi0xLjcNCiW" and many others

The link once added won't be changing.

Now, I have tried as above specified and I am currently trying to convert data to blob. Please feel free to provide better alternatives or point out possible mistakes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to familiarize yourself with the PDF Standard. A good starting point would be chapter 12.5.6.5 "Link annotations".
What you are trying to do is to put the whole file behind the link (by base64 encoding it). This would be a nice security hole if that would work.

You could add links (link annotations see ch. 12.5.6.5 table 176). Use the 'A' key which is an action dictionary. There you could add links to internal locations (like pages) or external locations like URLs. You could link to the files directly and this will then open the web browser and do whatever the web browser does (show the image, download the file ...)

There is the 'GoToE' action which references an embedded file (see the PDF spec/pdfbox documentation on how to add attachments) however from my understanding only PDF files are allowed:

> "allows jumping to or from a PDF file that is embedded in another PDF
> file"

But you want to link to other file types as well so that will not work.(Others may correct me if I am wrong here).
So you either add web links or your add your files as attachments - those are the options I currently see...

Comment: Thanks, It makes sense. I have added web links now.